# Implement a loader like jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

i've ajax loader data, and while loading i'd like to show a loader like jsfiddle. (the initialize the awesome).
I've find some ressources but none of them talk about this solution implementation.
Do you have some tips or ressources ?

Comment: Show an element when the requests starts. Hide it when the response is processed. In the element you can put a text, image, animation...

Comment: can you show your code to get coded answer :)